# como ocultar ion-header-bar ionic 1

Tags: angularjs, css, ionic

estoy tratando de ocultar ion-header-bar de tal forma que quede la imagen de fondo de todo bajo el butoom back y el title

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es el codigo de la vista

```
ion-view view-title="{{chat.name}}">
    <ion-content class="">
        <div class="perfilDomiciliarios">
            <img src="{{chat.face}}" class="imgBackDomi">
        </div>
        <div class="contImgPerfilDomi">
            <img src="{{chat.face}}" class="imgPerfilDomi">
            <h4>{{chat.name}}</h4>
        </div> 
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

queriendo lograr esta vista

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: echale un ojo a esto [enlace 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35053523/how-to-hide-header-bar-in-ionic), espero te sirva

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar con la etiqueta:

```
<ion-view hide-nav-bar="true"></ion-view>
```

Si eso no funciona podrías también ocultarlo desde el css pasando el atributo de hidden.

Saludos.

Comment: se oculta pero tambien se ocultaa el buttom back y no es la idea @Archagy

Comment: Entiendo, como en la imagen sugerida ya no veía el header (Y apenas note la flecha en la esquina superior) pensaba que el objetivo era ocultarlo. En todo caso lo mejor sería ocultar el header como lo sugerí y agregar una etiqueta `<span class="glyph-icon-right">` con su respectiva imagén y agregarle un ng-click para que cumpla su objetivo de regresar.